# Flutter Checkbox with the radio button logic

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, radio-button, flutter-widget

I have been trying to get the radio button functionality using checkboxes in flutter but I could not come up with a solution for this issue. Most of the examples I come across are with the ability to select multiple checkboxes.

Comment: What is it that you're specifically trying to do?  Is it a set of check-boxes, and you want the user to effectively be only able to check one at a time?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want

Comment: So, are you already familiar with setting the "state" in Flutter, and responding to that?  If so, then you need to be setting the state whenever a check-box value is changed, and in the "setState()" you'll need to set a variable that identifies which check-box was ticked.  The widgets will rebuild, and so then when you're rendering each check-box, you check each check-box (via id/property) against the variable that was set, and then only tick the check-box that was previously checked.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes but could you please give me a example on this.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really have time available to build up a working demo of what I've described.  As I said, if you're setting the state in the "onChanged" of each check-box, then you just need a variable to track which check-box was ticked, and then set the value (true/false) of each check-box accordingly when the widget builds.  You should make an attempt at this yourself, and then if you're still having issues you can post the specific code that you're working on, and that will help to diagnose any particular spots where you might be going wrong

Comment: okay got it. Thank you

Comment: @PriyanAbeyasekare, please check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the bellow code.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int index = 0;

class demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _demoState();
}

class _demoState extends State<demo> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 6,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  index = i;
                });
              },
              child: ListTile(
                leading: index == i
                    ? Icon(Icons.check_box)
                    : Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
                title: Text(i.toString()),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @PriyanAbeyasekare, Welcome, Please upvote me,